# Laravel Controller Function Run Twice

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel to controller my data when I create data it create twice.

Here is code in my food controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Food;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class FoodController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        error_log('geting food');
        return Food::all();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'food_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'food_type_id' => 'required|string|max:100|exists:food_types,id',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|between:0,99.99'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
        $food = Food::create(request()->all());

        error_log("Inserting");
        return $food;
    }
    public function getById($id){
        return Food::all()->find($id);
    }
    public function update(){
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'id'=> 'required|integer',
            'food_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'food_type_id' => 'required|string|max:100|exists:food_types,id',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|between:0,99.99'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
        $food=Food::where('id',request('id'))->get()[0];
        $food->fill(request()->all());
        $food->save();
        return $food;
    }
}
```

Here is the result after I request create once. I don't know what wrong of middleware or something else. It seem it do twice every single request.

[image]

Here is api my route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/


Route::post('login', 'UserController@authenticate');
Route::get('open', 'DataController@open');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function () {

    Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'food-type'],function(){
        Route::get('/','FoodTypeController@index');
        Route::get('/getById/{id}','FoodTypeController@getById');
        Route::post('/create','FoodTypeController@create');
        Route::post('/update','FoodTypeController@update');
        Route::delete('/delete','FoodTypeController@delete');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'food'],function(){
        Route::get('/','FoodController@index');
        Route::get('/getById/{id}','FoodController@getById');
        Route::post('/create','FoodController@create');
        Route::post('/update','FoodController@update');
        Route::delete('/delete','FoodController@delete');
    });
    // Route::get('closed', 'DataController@closed');
});
```

Here is my code in JWTMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;

class JwtMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Here is my post from postman

[image]

Comment: show your routes

Comment: Can you show the form or where you send this data to controller?

Comment: Not going to solve your problem, but I recommend you reading this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers . You should use standard function names for readability: index, show, create, store, edit, update, destroy

Comment: @NoOorZ24 thanks for your recomment. I'm new for laravel. I just try make api after I watch tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see that when I delete

```
 $response = $next($request);
```

from JwtMiddleware and then it work well thank you!.